# jquery.couch.js writing on restriced db

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb, nosql

I just can't write a doc on a non-public database. My database has a member and an admin. I have enabled CORS on the server. The auth via `$.couch.login` returns 200. But when I run `$.couch.db('name').saveDoc` I get a 401. Reading the docs, I really had no clue about it.
Off course the `$.couch.urlPrefix` was set.
Is there a way like, for example, curl (when you write name:psw@...) or I should implement something with `validate_doc_update`?
I am really fresh on couchdb.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I didn't like it I had to use a reverse proxy. There's no way to do that without get into same origin policy.
In my case, I didn't even wanted to serve an html from couchdb.